# Why can Oracle SDO project a point with a north bearing but not an east bearing?

Tags: java, oracle, geospatial

I'm using Oracle Spatial (SDO) to project a point at a given longitude, latitude along a given bearing for a given distance.  I'm looking for the longitude, latitude result of that.  This seems to work as expected when I project due North.  But not when projecting due East.

Projecting due North works like one would think.  The longitude if the outcome is exactly equal to the longitude of the start.

Projecting East does not work as expected.  The latitude if the outcome is NOT equal to the latitude of the start.  I can’t figure out why that is.

Here is an example case.

I’ll start with the case that works as expected.  I'm working with this output logged by my Java code.

> googlefiber3log4j:05:18:02.117
>   userObject.placement.OrthoRectangleSettings$CompleteRectOnServer -
>   [DEBUG] x: **-117.499208 y:
>   43.808064441203**=addVertex(num{0},rect{polygon:[[x: -117.499208 y: 37.220449]]}, stmt{Stmt(SQL{SELECT SDO_UTIL.POINT_AT_BEARING(?point?,?radians?,?distance?) point FROM
>   DUAL}) Properties: distance=**731519.9982059655**, point=**x:
>   -117.499208 y: 37.220449**, radians=**6.283185307179586**>})

In order of boldfaced text this shows the result of the calculation, the distance, the point we project, the angle to project.

Executed in sqlDev as:

> SELECT SDO_UTIL.POINT_AT_BEARING(sdo_geom.sdo_geometry(2001, 8192,
>   sdo_geom.sdo_point_type(-117.499208, 37.220449, NULL), NULL, NULL),
>   6.283185307179586,731519.9982059655) point FROM DUAL;

For Oracle a zero angle is North.  The 6.28… angle is essentially zero, based on 2 PI radians.

You can see that the resulting longitude -117.499208 is on both the input and output as expected.  For it to come out so clean I have to suspect that Oracle does not really use trig to do this and instead treats zero radians as a special case.

Now for the next calculation where I see the problem.  This will project east instead of north.  The point projected is the output from the above calculation.

> googlefiber3log4j:05:18:29.474
>   userObject.placement.OrthoRectangleSettings$CompleteRectOnServer -
>   [DEBUG] x: -101.232232142637 y: 42.6357376524045=
>   addVertex(num{1},rect{polygon:[[x: -117.499208 y: 37.220449, x:
>   -117.499208 y: 43.808064441203]]}, stmt{Stmt(SQL{SELECT SDO_UTIL.POINT_AT_BEARING(?point?,?radians?,?distance?) point FROM
>   DUAL}) Properties: distance=1325879.999986927, point=x: -117.499208 y:
>   43.808064441203, radians= 1.5707963267948966>})

Executed in sqlDev as:

> SELECT SDO_UTIL.POINT_AT_BEARING(sdo_geom.sdo_geometry(2001, 8192,
>   sdo_geom.sdo_point_type(-117.499208, 43.808064441203, NULL), NULL,
>   NULL),
>   1.5707963267948966,1325879.999986927) point FROM DUAL;

In this case the radians are 90.0 degrees/east.  So I would expect the latitude of the result (42.6357376524045) to be equal to the latitude of the start (43.808064441203).  But it is actually quite a bit south of that.

Why, when attempting to project due east, would the latitude change at all?

Answer (score 0):

The short (and overdue) answer is "No, when offsetting a point East to a new point, the Latitude should not change."

However, I think you have uncovered a bug/feature in Oracle's `Point_at_Bearing()` utility.

I tested Oracle 11.2 with a variant of your code, where I made two changes:

1. I simplified the numbers to make the offset more visible
2. I used `CONVERT_UNIT()` to get exact radian conversion from 90 degrees

Next, I iterated (on input bearing) until I got the same output Latitude as input. for the area near Little Valley, Oregon, the result looks like this:

```
SELECT SDO_UTIL.POINT_AT_BEARING(
    sdo_geom.sdo_geometry(
        2001
        , 8192
        , sdo_geom.sdo_point_type(
            -117.5
            ,44
            , null)
        , NULL
        , NULL)
    , SDO_UTIL.CONVERT_UNIT(
        84.2316805
        , 'degree'
        ,'radian') 
    , 1325000.0) aPoint FROM DUAL;
```

So, the long answer is:  It is likely that Oracle is using a non-conformal projection in order to get offset coordinates; as a result, the Latitude is incorrectly adjusted.  Said another way, the angular distortion of the `Point_at_Bearing()` function at your Latitude is more than 5.7 degrees!

Answer (score 0):

Travelling due east would mean along a rhumb line; a parallel of latitude is a rhumb line so the latitude would not change. But this isn't what SDO_UTIL.POINT_AT_BEARING does, it uses the distance along a geodesic or colloquially a great circle (this is the shortest distance - the equivalent of a straight line on the surface of the earth). The geodesic is due east only at the specified point; as you travel along it the direction changes away from the nearest pole - the example case is in the northern hemisphere so it goes to the south. If you travel half the circumference of the earth, you will get to a point as far south of the equator as the start point was north.